# Microsoft word: How to display text outside a heading?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

In `Microsoft WORD 2016`, how can we start adding text outside a `Heading`. For example, as shown below, I have a `Heading1` whose content has three bulleted items. But, after those bulleted items, I want to start typing text outside the `Heading1`. But, as expected, any text added after `Heading1` gets included inside `Heading1`. I want that text to be outside `Heading1`. Please help.

**Remark**: I tried hitting `Enter` multiple times after item3, and then adding new line but WORD keeps including that newline inside `Heading1`. I've verified it by collapsing `Heading1` and noticing that the new line gets hidden inside collapsed `Heading1`.

[image]

Comment: Sample pictures is gone or dead.

Comment: @StackUser2949052 I can still see the sample picture. It could be a browser issue. I'm using `MS Edge`. Can you try in a different browser?

Comment: Opera. It's working (again). I haven't even updated the cache or anything. But also the URL didn't work before. All is good now.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to place the cursor at the beginning of the paragraph that you don't want to be collapsed with the heading, and then insert a continuous section break (on the **Layout** tab, in the **Page Setup** group, click **Breaks** > **Continuous**). A downside is, that when you collapse the heading, there will be a paragraph's worth of space between it and the next paragraph, where the section break sits – though maybe you won't mind this extra space.

Otherwise, as you've seen, collapsing a heading 1 collapses everything until the next heading 1. So I'd just define a new style based on Heading 1, and set **Frame** properties for it so that it sits at the edge of the page, with surrounding text wrapping around it. I'd also reduce the font size, line spacing, and space before/after settings for the paragraph, maybe also changing the font color to white, though these changes aren't strictly necessary (they just help hide any evidence of the paragraph's presence, especially when formatting marks are visible in Word). That way, I can just insert a blank paragraph before the paragraph that I don't want collapsed, and apply the new style. It will be tucked out of the way at the edge of the page, more or less invisible, but will still be present in the document's outline as the next heading 1. As long as no text is entered in that heading paragraph, it won't show up in the TOC, if you insert one, though it will appear as a blank heading in the navigation pane.